# Как в pyproject.toml указать дополнительные файлы которые должны быть включены?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Есть некая библиотека для Python. Её нет на PyPi по некоторым техническим причинам. Устанавливается через GitFlic.

Вот ссылка: https://gitflic.ru/project/pyne/raw_pyne

При установке:

```sh
pip install git+https://gitflic.ru/project/pyne/raw_pyne.git
```

Всё устанавливается.

Но при запуске не находиться какой-то файл, не `.py` а `.jpg`.

Проблема в том, что при установке загрузились только `.py` файлы.

Как в `pyproject.toml` указать дополнительные файлы которые должны быть включены?

Comment: Дайте полный текст команды с адресом вашего проекта. Мы-то не видим что у вас там.

Comment: @Глеб добавил ссылку.

Comment: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html

Comment: @Namerek никакие инструкции не работают, можете сами если знаете написать объективный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент похоже средствами только `pyproject.toml` при использовании `setuptools` это невозможно сделать: [Setuptools -- Replacing Manifest.in with pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77052495/4752653).

Если использовать poetry (или другие подобные инструменты, по ссылке выше упоминается hatch) - без проблем, см. документацию для poetry, например: [include and exclude](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude)

Если использовать все же `setuptools`, придется добавить отдельный файл `MANIFEST.in`, см. документацию: [Controlling files in the distribution](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html)

Минимальный пример:

```
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    └── test_include_file
        ├── __main__.py
        └── test.txt
```

pyproject.toml:

```
[project]
name = "test-include-file"
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

MANIFEST.in:

```
include src/test_include_file/test.txt
```

`__main__.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path

base_path = Path(__file__).parent
print(base_path)

file_path = base_path / "test.txt"
print("File exists?", file_path.exists())

text = file_path.read_text(encoding="utf-8")
print("Text:", text)
```

text.txt:

```
Какой-то текст
```

Тестируем:

```
❯ python -m venv .venv
❯ source .venv/bin/activate
❯ pip install .
Processing /home/user/Projects/test_include
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: test-include-file
  Building wheel for test-include-file (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for test-include-file: filename=test_include_file-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=1573 sha256=4d1e336550edce260f12f0d44095fa1397b8d2dcfeb07de1d7ab347aa77ee950
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-l91m2smm/wheels/ac/5e/e2/189d83e584af124bd4723ea850b04b29f7d675ac469e5cf5a6
Successfully built test-include-file
Installing collected packages: test-include-file
Successfully installed test-include-file-0.1.0
❯ python -m test_include_file
/home/user/Projects/test_include/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/test_include_file
File exists? True
Text: Какой-то текст
```

Если убрать файл MANIFEST.in, напишет `File exists? False` и упадет при попытке его прочитать.